# Best way of making a trip-wire type device?

Tags: infrared, motion, laser, range-detector

I'm wanting to make a type of electronic "trip wire".

My basic idea is to have like a laser and basically when the laser is interrupted then it sends some signal to a microprocessor.

I'm not tied to a laser but it was the first thing that comes to mind. The attributes it needs to have is it needs to be only like a "wire"(as in, it doesn't detect motion anywhere but head on) and it needs to be low power(like run for a few days at least off of 2 AAs). Also, an actual wire is out of the question because it needs to be capable of being "reset" after a certain time out(of say 1 second or so) The range it needs to work with is only 5 or 10 feet though. Also, it's not possible to have two parts to this device like a typical laser-photodiode setup. This needs to be contained all in one (preferably small) package.

What is my best bet with this? I was thinking maybe super-sonic sound like [this](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/639) but I think there would probably be a better way.

So basically what I have in mind for the device is like when you first set it up, you "calibrate" it for a certain distance. So for instance if there is a wall five feet in front of it, then this device would work if there was anything that came head-on with it in 5 feet. And etc.

Comment: What should trip the wire, and what shouldn't? Eg: fog, rain, pant leg, wheel hub? Also, can you install a mirror/shiny thing on the other side?

Comment: @tybl Well I would want it to be half resistant to things like fog and rain. But basically I'd want for say a leg or animal or something like that to trigger it. And no a mirror can't be installed. It has to all be contained in one box basically.

Comment: Maybe something like a ultra sonic sonar may work better in the foggy or smokey conditions.

Comment: Nah, a laser is a good idea. Will post about it tomorrow if [someone else doesn't](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6297/any-published-designs-for-time-of-flight-laser-distance-measurement).

Comment: Mirrors are a pain to install; you'd use a retroreflector instead of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple options for such a thing.

1. Ultra sonic sonar
2. PIR sensor, used in security systems

Your best bet I think is to use a PIR sensor like [this one](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8630).

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements:

- **line-of-sight activation**: this means focusing lenses & apertures for LEDs, or a laser.
- **self-contained unit**: this means it must register a reflection from a variety of surfaces.
- **low power**: doesn't really limit implementations, but puts some design constraints on them.

There are two options:

1. **Infrared emitter and detector package**, like the [one linked](http://www.ladyada.net/media/sensors/PNA4602.pdf) in [Matt's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8374/best-way-of-making-a-trip-wire-type-device/8395#8395), but with a [focusing lens](http://www.dialight.com/Assets/Brochures_And_Catalogs/Illumination/MDEXLUMADBOGD.pdf) or aperture or a small viewing angle.

   - Focusing lens, aperture, or small viewing angle is required to maintain directionality.
   - Focusing lens or aperture would be a pain in the butt, and could only be tuned for certain distance ranges.
   - Viewing angles as low as 6<sup>o</sup> are available. Geometry will tell you what kind of directionality this gives you at a distance.
2. **Laser and photodiode**: Lasers are available with focusing lens and aperture [for less than $5 each](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.13378); photodiodes are [about the same](http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TAOS/TSL252R-LF/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtWNtIk7yMEscFVjdrg3sSauchWfwSrPGg%3d). I would use a visible one to make aiming it easier (but require bandpass filtering around carrier frequency to filter out ambient), but it's up to you: there are IR and <sup>(expensive!)</sup> UV laser diodes. It may take a bit of experimentation to develop an algorithm that filters out ambient effectively and detects weak reflections. [This guy](http://www.lucidscience.com/pro-laser%20spy%20device-1.aspx) did something like it. Note that some surfaces will simply gobble up a visible beam (eg. flat black).

For **low power operation**, use sleep modes, pull-up PMOS FETs for *always-on* devices, including voltage divider branches (stop current drain when controller is *off*), and activate the sensor intermittently. It doesn't sound like it needs to capture any fast single-shot events; going with 20km/h and 10cm objects, a 0<sup>o</sup> (perfect line) detector would get **18ms** to react, or just over 55Hz. You could wake-up every 10-15ms, check the *line-of-sight* a few times, then go back to sleep. With a switching (or [no](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8112/how-do-i-convert-9-v-dc-to-5-v/8118#8118)) regulator and some intelligent power budgeting in the design phase, you'll easily get this to run for days on AAs.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 555 timer to output 38khz to an [infrared led](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9349) and use an [IR detector](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266) to output a high signal when the led is pointed at the detector. when the beam is broken, you can trigger an interrupt on the micro. There are lots of details [on this ladyada tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/sensors/ir.html)