# Looking for a miniature low-power range detector for a robot

Tags: distance, proximity-sensor

Sorry if I am not following guidelines.

I am a noob trying to build a Robot for learning purposes - I want to play with navigation algorithms using particular measurements - distance to the obstacle along a straight line. I know there are many other ways to skin the cat, but I want it this way.
I have been looking online for a sensor that would help me, but there are so many options and none of the are ideal. My requirements:

- Can sense distance between 1 foot (30 cm) and and 15 feet (5m); ideally between 10 cm and 10 meters (I'll accept infinity as the upper bound :) ).
- Is directional, not shotgun-like. Ideally, at 10 feet (3 meters), the sensor would bounce back if the bounding sphere the size of a tennis ball would contain a wall. (Hopefully this makes sense - this translates to a cone with a certain angle).
- Is small - no bigger than a human eyeball including casing.
- Is low voltage/power - so that I can make it draw power from a usb cable, perhaps adding some sort of converter, but hopefully not.
- Functions in complete dark, or near-dark.
- Is under $20 per piece (I might buy 10 in bulk).
- has distance resolution of at least 10 cm (4 inches); higher is better.

It does not have to be sample the data very fast; even 10 times per second will do.
Hopefully this question is withing the guidelines. Again sorry, I do not have previous robotics experience.

Comment: What have you tried? Ultrasonics probably OK except for wide angle. 4" resolution is very "low". Should be easy :-). OTS tape measures MAY be an easy path.

Comment: I'd vote ultrasonics too, but size might be a problem: most US modules use separate transmitter and receiver, each ~ 1 cm in diameter, with some distance in between. And US tend to be rather wide-beam. Some sort of barrel around sender and/or transmitter might help.

Comment: An alternative, that still won't meet your requirements, could be the Sharp range of IR sensors. They come in different flavours, but could be worth considering.

Comment: For a 10 centimeter object detection precision (larger than the tennis ball mentioned) at a distance of 3 meters, you require an s-angle of 6 degrees. That is rather narrow for ultrasonic sensors, are you sure you need that precision? Laser based LIDAR or even DIY hobby-laser-based sensors could achieve this, but the cost goes up significantly. See [this project](http://coolarduino.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/arduino-laser-3d-tracking-range-finder/) for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to compromise on at least one of those requirements. The normal way of doing this sort of thing on small robots is ultrasound, e.g. http://dx.com/p/ultrasonic-sensor-distance-measuring-module-138563

That fails your "directionality" and probably "size" requirement, but is cheap and effective. There are smaller, narrower ones: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/639

If directionality is really important, I don't think there's any substitute for doing it with a laser. There's a discussion here: [Any published designs for time-of-flight laser distance measurement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6297/any-published-designs-for-time-of-flight-laser-distance-measurement) , but the engineering involved is not simple and I can't find any modules implementing it. The "time of flight resonance" technique looks best to me, although the round-trip time for 15cm is 1ns => 1GHz signal. That's going to make for tricky PCB design and isn't feasible for a beginner.

Comment: There's the option of laser-based angular measurement, very similar to the process used in the Sharp IR proximity sensors... The link on my other comment has a project implementing this by laser + webcam.

Comment: Thank you! The one from sparkfun.com looks promising. There is also the EZ4 version that supposeddly has a narrower beam - https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8504 Price is the easiest option to compromise on.